# Chai.Js assertion question/ where can I find resources?

Tags: node.js, chai

I need to do the two following, where can I begin to start learning?

Write test assertions using Chai.Js that would validate:

1. 200 response code
2. John Doe exists as an “advisorName” value in the response data

Answer (score 0):

```
pm.test("Status code is 200", function() {
  pm.response.to.have.status(200);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.